# Use jQuery to get selected values from items only

Tags: jquery

I have a series of divs as follows.

```
<div class="apartment-entry-container">
 a bunch of other HTML
 <input type="checkbox" value=",<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
</div>
```

I get the "bunch of HTML" and create a single js variable from only the divs that contain a checked checkbox using the following.

```
jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked)').each(function() {
   content += jQuery(this).html();                      
});
```

I would like to pass an additional value into the mix by getting a $post->ID for example. So i figured the following would work.

```
jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked)').each(function() {
   content += jQuery(this).html();  
   postidstring += jQuery(this).val();                      
});
```

I know im missing something something in the way of the selector there and that Im in effect trying to get the value of the container but, how do I select the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Just an unrelated tip: adding a comma to the value just for creating a separated value list is pretty hackish. It'd be cleaner to leave out the comma, make `postidstring` an array and `postidstring.push( jQuery(this).find(':checkbox').val() )` and later `postidstring.join(',')` when you need to convert it into a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're working on the container div, and not on the input field, so your `jQuery(this)` refers to the div. So `jQuery(this).val()` does not make sense, even though it is the right way to access the checkbox had `this` been referring to it.

In order to get this working you need to change your code so that it actually selects the input and not the div:
`jQuery(this).find('input').val();`, then you're code would look like this:

```
jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked').each(function() {
   content += jQuery(this).html();  
   postidstring += jQuery(this).find('input').val();                      
});
```

Comment: I like your solution however, when I console.log(poststringid) its coming back as undefined.

Comment: Can you post the lifecycle of `poststringid`? Right now we can only see where you set it, but not where you first declare it, and where you `console.log(poststringid)` it.

Comment: You just solved it. I forgot to declare an empty variable for poststringid.

Comment: Figured that ;) Classic mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery(this)` represents the `div` that contains the checkbox, not the checkbox. Try:

```
jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').val();
```

The `find` function will pull all child elements that match the given selector.